# MemoryError при обучении большого набора данных с использованием наивного байесовского классификатора

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn

Я пытаюсь обучить наивный байесовский классификатор, используя набор ключевых слов для разных категорий. 
Данные хранятся в данном виде:

```
type(train)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Всего у меня около 22 тысяч категорий(соответственно, такая размерность), при обучении которых возникает ошибка memoryerror:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
model.fit(train.astype('U'), categories.astype('U'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему? Как можно сократить кол-во затрачиваемой памяти?

При меньшем кол-ве данных, модель обучается

Comment: какие размерности входных датасетов: `train` и `categories`? И сколько ненулевых элементов у разреженной матрицы, полученной на выходе `TfidfVectorizer()`?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете train.astype('U')? У вас TfidfVectorizer делает sparse matrix на выходе, которая очень экономит место. И MultinomialNB умеет принимать на вход разреженные матрицы.

Comment: Ещё можно поиграться параметрами TfidfVectorizer, например min_df и max_features, чтобы сократить число фич, это может позволить сэкономить место.